# resharper set using on multiple files

Tags: c#, resharper, using

I generate a lot of classes with T4 templates.
Every time I do this I have to add the using directive by hand (via Resharper 8 which suggest the right directive.)
Is it possible to do this for multiple classes with one click? Something like adjust namespaces for all the classes in project.

PS: I don't want to change the T4 template, but if Reshaper can't do this, this could be a possible solution.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
A little bit more explained:
I generate classes which are derived from a handcoded baseclass. The using for the baseclass will not be set via the T4 template. So I have to set it "by hand". Or in my case I want to know if Resharper can do it on multiple classes in one action.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. ReSharper 8 has a new [Fix in Scope](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/10/fix-in-scope-a-new-code-cleanup-experience-in-resharper-8/) feature, but this seems to fall short of fixing namespaces across a project/solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the 'Move to namespace...' refactoring if you want to rename a template namespace in your entire solution.

**Edit**
Otherwise its not possible with R# to bulk insert an arbitrary using statement to multiple files. You will need to put your hands on the T4 templates in such a case.

Comment: Sorry but that is not what I meant. The namespace of the class is correct. But for my baseclass of the generated class the using directive is not set. Resharper sees the correct reference and adds it with the alt+enter shortcut.

Comment: I was afraid so. Thanks